# How to add a value to an array list using Scanner class

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to ask how can I add a value to the arraylist using Scanner class without declaring any variable.

```
List<Integer> cl = new ArrayList<>(); 
List<String> al = new ArrayList<>(); 
    
System.out.println("Enter the name of the account user");
String name = si.next();
System.out.println("Enter the amount you want to deposit in your account");
int amount= si.nextInt();
cl.add(amount);
al.add(name);
```

Like in this code I want to add values to the array list without using the variables name and amount.

Comment: `cl.add(si.nextInt());` and well, the same for the name

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: In reality, the best thing you can do is create a Customer class which contains `name`, `balance`, `depositAmount`, etc as class instance variables then you only need one List of Customer: `List<Customer>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Scanner si = new Scanner(System.in);

List<Integer> cl = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();

System.out.println("Enter the name of the account user");
al.add(si.nextLine());
System.out.println("Enter the amount you want to deposit in your account");
cl.add(si.nextInt());
si.nextLine();
```

The `nextLines` are for if you want to use the scanner after this code, now there won't still be new line characters in the scanner that could mess up your input.
I also swapped `next()` for `nextLine()` in case you'd want to enter a name that contains spaces. (`nextLine()` returns everything until there's a `\n` and it also drops the `\n`.)